# Linking VB to MS Accsss Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to link a VB application with a MS access database.

The only way I seem able to do this is through adding a data source. Is there a way or doing this so you use it as an external and code to the file location rather than actually uploading the database to vb?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Data.Oledb


    Dim con As New OledbConnection("Provider=microsoft.Jet.oledb.4.0DataSource=D:\mydata.mdb;")

    Dim cmd As New OledbCommand



    Public Sub New()
        con.Open()

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table1"

    End Sub
```

Comment: where you say table1, my database has 3 tables how does that work

Comment: "SELECT * FROM table1" ,"SELECT * FROM table2" , "SELECT * FROM table3"

Comment: would you be willing to help me with my project ? one a 1-to-1 basis? I have team viewer and think i could learn a lot from you